# How to set a default value on Lightning Component Option Select without changing the order

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, picklist, aura, lightningselect

Can someone help me with this line of code as I am still new to Development and learning it. On the below lightning component code, the default value shows as "Call" and now the business needs the default value as "GoTo Meeting". I was told instead of changing the order of the lines on the code we can add a default tag to set it.

```
<lightning:Select name = "recalsend" label = "Meeting Type" required = "true" value = "{! v.meetingType }">    
                    <option value="Call">Call</option>
                    <option value="Onsite Visit">Onsite Visit</option>  
                    <option value="GoToMeeting">GoToMeeting</option>
                </lightning:Select>
```

The default value need to be GOTO Meeting instead of Call Option. How can i explicitly define here?

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: P.S. Pay attention to your code. `<lightning:Select` is incorrect, it should be `<lightning:select`. JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe, so a single mixup can cause things to break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the default value of meetingType to be GoToMeeting. Like below

```
<aura:attribute name="meetingType" type="String" default="GoToMeeting"/>
```

Comment: @AmandaGreen It needs to be in the same component, somewhere above the code you wrote. It's traditional to write attributes at the top of the component.

Comment: @Menachem Shanowitz: thanks for the reply. I was able to make it work as you mentioned. thanks a lot :)